# Запретить копировать зависимости в выходную директорию

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Можно ли настроить проект так, что бы определенные зависимости не копировались в выходную директорию?

Почему это потребовалось? Разобрался с фреймворком [prism](/questions/tagged/prism) и получил то что необходимо, а если быть точнее, если модуль отсутствует в папке с плагинами, то он не будет загружен, но т.к. модули подгружают все что необходимо из основного приложения, отвалилась необходимость в зависимостях самого [prism](/questions/tagged/prism), и не хотелось бы после каждого билда вручную чистить папку с плагинами.

Есть ли возможность настроить проект так, что бы некоторые из зависимостей не копировались?

Comment: "Copy Local" - false?

Comment: @Igor: Точно!!! Запишите ответом...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В свойствах Reference-ных сборок:

`"Copy Local" - False`